# How to get midi event length using Naudio

Tags: c#, winforms, midi, naudio

How can I find out the length of each midi event in order to play it correctly. Here is an example of some code, but the durations are most likely incorrect

```
var midi = new MidiFile(path);
midiOut = new MidiOut(0);

var a = midi.Events.GetTrackEvents(1).ToArray();
for(int i=1;i<a.Length;i++)
{
    if (MidiEvent.IsNoteOn(a[i - 1]) && ((NoteOnEvent)a[i-1]).NoteLength>0)
    {
        if (a[i].DeltaTime == a[i - 1].DeltaTime)
        {
            midiOut.Send(MidiMessage.StartNote(((NoteOnEvent)a[i]).NoteNumber, 127, 1).RawData);
            Thread.Sleep(a[i + 1].DeltaTime);
            i++;
            continue;
        }else
        {
            midiOut.Send(MidiMessage.StartNote(((NoteOnEvent)a[i - 1]).NoteNumber, 127, 1).RawData);
            Thread.Sleep(((NoteOnEvent)a[i - 1]).NoteLength); //(a[i].DeltaTime*4)/3
        }
    }else if (MidiEvent.IsNoteOff(a[i-1]))
    {
        midiOut.Send(MidiMessage.StopNote(((NoteOnEvent)a[i - 1]).NoteNumber, 127, 1).RawData);
        Thread.Sleep(a[i].DeltaTime);
    }
}
```

I also need to implement a MIDI recording function using virtual piano keys in Win Forms, any ideas on how this can be done?

The Naudio library is incomprehensible to me, at least due to my poor knowledge of English, the library documentation does not quite answer all my questions

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect from constructions like these?

```
Thread.Sleep(a[i].DeltaTime);
```

Please see the docs on the [Thread.Sleep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep#system-threading-thread-sleep(system-int32)) method. You can notice that it accepts `int` parameter which represents **milliseconds**. And then please see [the spec](https://www.midi.org/specifications-old/item/the-midi-1-0-specification) on MIDI (including Standard MIDI Files). Delta-time doesn't represent milliseconds, its value is in **ticks**. Ticks has nothing in common with milliseconds. There are plenty of answers on the web showing how to convert MIDI time to metric one:

- [How to get Exact Time of a MIDI event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070510/how-to-get-exact-time-of-a-midi-event/44982901#44982901)
- [Midi timestamp in seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063437/midi-timestamp-in-seconds/44175419#44175419)
- [How long is a MIDI file note in milliseconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71984337/how-long-is-a-midi-file-note-in-milliseconds/71986822#71986822)

More than that `Thread.Sleep` will block your current thread. More more than that the minimum interval you can sleep with this method is 15.6 ms on Windows so you have great chance your playback will drift.

I can recommend you the [DryWetMIDI](https://github.com/melanchall/drywetmidi) library (I'm the author of it) which provides Playback API allowing to play MIDI files precisely and in non-blocking manner:

```
using Melanchall.DryWetMidi.Multimedia;
using Melanchall.DryWetMidi.Core;

// ...

var midiFile = MidiFile.Read("YourFile.mid");

var outputDevice = OutputDevice.GetByName("MidiDeviceName");
var playback = midiFile.GetPlayback(outputDevice);

playback.Start();
```

Read more about playback in [Playback](https://melanchall.github.io/drywetmidi/articles/playback/Overview.html) article of the library docs.